# How to get list of active IP and MAC address in a subnet for osx

Tags: c, macos

I was writing an application in C code where i would require to get list of IP and MAC address of all devices active on the particular subnet(in particular wifi subnet).
i found a script file which does the same using nmap but this command line tool is not available in every machines(separate installation required).below is the script file location.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19783/how-do-i-know-the-ip-addresses-of-other-computers-in-my-network

is there any other way to achieve the above mentioned without time delay, sample code or command will help.

Thanks in advance.

I did lot of research and i found some answers in net but none of them are helping me to achieve the desired result.

Comment: What about running broadcast ping or ping for every IP address in the subnet?

Comment: as i mentioned below broadcast ping is not serving my purpose and pinging each ip will take more time atleast 3 mins which will be too much for my application requirement

Answer (score 2):

A simple way with default tools in OSX is using `ping xxx.xxx.xxx.255` broadcast IP, then take a look at [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) table with `arp -a` command to list available machines in you subnet.

It is important to first `ping` and then look at `arp` table, because arp cache table stores the machine IPs that you had a connection with them.

Comment: Just like the answers in the question the OP links to?

Comment: @trojanfoe The important thing is first pinging the broadcast IP and then looking at ARP table. However that link contains both facts but in separate.

Comment: I did try the above mentioned method ,first i emptied arp table and ran ping broadcast IP then when i typed arp -a result was --- 192.168.90.255 ping statistics ---
127 packets transmitted, 127 packets received, +254 duplicates, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.183/8.220/341.990/25.879 ms
Mac:~ root# arp -a
 (192.168.90.1) at 94:10:3e:4:a9:d2 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
 (192.168.90.100) at 28:e3:47:9:72:ae on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
 (192.168.90.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
moreover it is taking lot of time which does not match for my requirement.

Comment: i am doing this in wifi network , i know that there are 25 devices active on this network but result was omething  else

Comment: @Darshan Not all devices answer to broadcast ping.

Comment: i did test this method in LAN as well but result remained the same. So when i am using nmap command all devices are responding , it is obvious that pinging broadcast IP method is not recommended.

Comment: @Darshan Yes it is not as accurate as `nmap` acts, because `nmap` may use other methods or a combinations of them.